# Javascript arithmetic operations with switch case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have two input for number1 and number2 with four buttons("+", "-", "*", "/")

I want to get operation value from button and pass it to switch case.

How do I do that?

```js
function calculate() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  var islem = document.getElementsByTagName("button").value;
  console.log(num1);
  console.log(num2);
  console.log(islem);
  switch (islem) {
    case "+":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case "-":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case "*":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case "/":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").innerHTML = num1 / num2;
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="1. sayı">
<input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="2. sayı">
<div>
  <ol>
    <button onclick="calculate()" value="+">[ + ] Topla</button>
    <button onclick="calculate()" value="-">[ - ] Çıkar</button>
    <button onclick="calculate()" value="*">[ * ] Çarp</button>
    <button onclick="calculate()" value="/">[ / ] Böl</button>
  </ol>
</div>

<input type="number" id="sonuc" placeholder="Sonuç">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proper?"

Comment: @Taki: Only if the code actually works.

Comment: It's in a code snippet. Try running it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey sorry I didn't express myself correctly.

Comment: I'm just asking how do I get operand value from the button?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I edited my post. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making two mistakes

- `getElementsByTagName` returns list of element. You should use `this` inside of `calculate` to get the clicked button.
- The `value` is always a string you need to convert it to a number for mathematical operations.

Here is the code

```js
function calculate(button) {
  var num1 = +document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var num2 = +document.getElementById("num2").value;
  var operator = button.getAttribute('value');
  switch (operator) {
    case "+":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").value = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case "-":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").value = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case "*":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").value = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case "/":
      document.getElementById("sonuc").value = num1 / num2;
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="1. sayı">
<input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="2. sayı">
<div>
  <ol>
    <button onclick="calculate(this)" value="+">[ + ] Topla</button>
    <button onclick="calculate(this)" value="-">[ - ] Çıkar</button>
    <button onclick="calculate(this)" value="*">[ * ] Çarp</button>
    <button onclick="calculate(this)" value="/">[ / ] Böl</button>
  </ol>
</div>

<input type="number" id="sonuc" placeholder="Sonuç">
```

The above is not the best way to handle this problem. So the fixes you need to make your code the best one are:

- Create list of objects which contains contains information(`text` and function to perform on calculation) about each operator
- Loop thourgh the array and create button for each element.
- Add the listener to that button dynamically and use that function of object to calculate the values.
- declare the input elements as global variables so you don't need to call them again and again

```js
const operatorsCont = document.querySelector('#operatorsCont');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
const num1 = document.querySelector('#num1');
const num2 = document.querySelector('#num2');
const operators = [
  {text: '+', func: (a, b) => a + b},
  {text: '-', func: (a, b) => a - b},
  {text: '*', func: (a, b) => a * b},
  {text: '/', func: (a, b) => a / b},
]

operators.forEach(op => {
  const elm = document.createElement('button');
  elm.innerHTML = op.text;
  elm.onclick = function(){
    output.value = op.func(+num1.value, +num2.value);
  }
  operatorsCont.appendChild(elm)
})
```

```html
<div id="operatorsCont">
</div>
<input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="1. sayı">
<input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="2. sayı">


<input type="number" id="output" placeholder="Sonuç">
```

Comment: It still gets + value

Comment: I got the logic. thank you for the edit @Titus

Comment: But I still don't get the downvotes :/

Comment: @KenanKazım I have added a  better and more dynamic way of create a calculator. Make sure to see that. Ask if you don't understand. And don't care about downvotes just keep learning

Comment: the thing is I want it to be in simple javascript. By the way addition operation just concatenates numbers like 1+1 = 11

Comment: @KenanKazım Fixed that

Comment: Is it possible to implement it in simple javascript? no frameworks involved.

Comment: @KenanKazım Yes I made the second snippet. It doesn't include anything other than simple javascript.

Comment: Looks like '+' character in front of the +document.getElementById("num1").value; fixes it. What is the reason? Thanks again.

Comment: @KenanKazım It converts string into number. `'3'` to `3`

Comment: Oh, that explains it. Great! learned so much today